# ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 10 Intel (14") for Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, laptop, thinkpad, compatibility

I wanted to check how the ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 10 Intel (14") is for running the Ubuntu 22.04 OS. I am quite a noob here, and found that this laptop satisfies a lot of the hardware requirements I'd need for my work. However, the only thread I can find here with this laptop and linux is from a year ago.

Therefore, I wanted to check if anyone can share their opinions on using this with Ubuntu? If not, would you recommend any other laptop with similar specs? Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.  *This is a Question & Answer site don't forget, not a forum; you've presented no actual problem to be solved*

Comment: There’s a 10th Gen X1 Carbon now? I didn’t realize my 5th Gen was so old. Time flies when nothing breaks …

Answer (score 0):

This model has been certified with Ubuntu, see [this page](https://ubuntu.com/certified/202204-30215). However, this doesn't mean that there will be no hardware problems or glitches whatsoever.

[An older reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/tqyyc1/thinkpad_x1_carbon_gen_10_with_linux/) reported some minor issues. As of 1-2 years ago, when that thread was made, the general reports were that it works with Ubuntu 22, but there are some glitches with certain hardware, including secure boot, dolby effect, face recognition, and the Tile tracker. One user had some trouble installing but got it to work.

Although the reputation for the ThinkPad line's compatibility with linux is pretty good across-the-board, at the time of that thread, it was a cutting edge model and there seemed to be a consensus that support for it was shaky.

However, it could be that most or all of these kinks have been worked out.

If you are absolutely wedded to a particular aspect of hardware working, I would research the compatibility with the specific hardware component before buying. If you just want a system that works for the basics, then this system will likely work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thinkpads have a long history of very good support by Linux and especially Ubuntu.  Lenovo also offer Ubuntu pre-installed on some models (typically those with the "Build Your Thinkpad" option) and in several geographical regions.

A Thinkpad X1 Carbon that comes pre-install with Linux should make the most of all available hardware.

Unless someone is very experienced with Ubuntu and Lenovo, I would suggest getting Ubuntu pre-installed simply for peace of mind.

For example, in my region the Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 11 can be purchased with Ubuntu Linux pre-installed or without an operating system, as well as the typical Windows options.

Even without buying the Thinkpad X1 Gen 10 without Ubuntu pre-installed, its likely that all of the core features will simply work without any additional configuration.

There is a small chance that niche or very new hardware features many need newer kernel versions or additional software.  If a specific piece of hardware is essential then searching Ubuntu support with the hardware name and laptop model should show if others have had issues.  None of that should be neccessary though if bought with Ubuntu pre-installed.